# update table with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I can`t update my table. Maybe you can see where is problem.
Edit works fine. It brings value to the fields. If i erase {{ method_field('PUT') }} it saves values normally, but i need to UPDATE

It`s my UPDATE controller

```
public function update(Request $request, Radar $radar)
{
    Radar::update([
        'date' => $request->input('date'),
        'number' => $request->input('number'),
        'distance' => $request->input('distance'),
        'time' => $request->input('time'),            
        ]);

     return redirect('/radars');
}
```

Thats how my view looks like:

```
<form action="{{ url('/radars')}}" method="post" > 
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Routes:

```
Route::put('radars/{radar}', 'RadarsController@update');
```

Error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Your form action doesn't have a `driver` on the end of it

Comment: wrong driver. sorry. but its not the case

Comment: Let me know if my answer is incorrect and I'll delete it

Comment: @Djave why have you deleted your answer? It's correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify ID:

```
{{ url('/radars/') . $radar->id }}
```

Also, you need to use object and not just a model class. Something like:

```
public function update(Request $request, Radar $radar)
{
    $radar->update($request->all());

    return redirect('/radars');
}
```

Comment: <form action="{{ url('/radars')}}" i made because (after corrections in form) i want come back to main site. I tried to change route to /radars, but still no luck

Comment: @Darius check the rendered link, it's definitely should be something like `/radars/5` and not `/radars`. Then check `$radar` variable inside the `update` method with `dd($radar)`. It should show you a real `Radar` object and not `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request

```
Radar::update(Request::all());
```

Comment: Show same error. Its look like there is no connection between edit form and update

Comment: MethodNotAllowedHttpException with no No message

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it, I think it should be like the below:

```
<form action="{{ url('/radars/' . $radar->id )}}" method="post" >
```

If you look, you're posting to `/radars` but your route is `radars/{driver}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add where statement to tell which record to update and dont

```
Radar::where('id',$id)->update([
        'date' => $request->input('date'),
        'number' => $request->input('number'),
        'distance' => $request->input('distance'),
        'time' => $request->input('time'),            
        ]);
```

return redirect('/radars');

Answer (score 0):

If you are using resource route, then in your form, you need to change action from:

```
url('/radars')
```

to

```
route('radars.update', $radar)
```

and keep the following:

```
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```